# bag of words model not making sense

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, nlp

I made a bag of words model and when I printed it out, the output is not quite making sense. 
This is my code I used to initalise the bag of words:

```
#creating the bag of words model

headline_bow = CountVectorizer()
headline_bow.fit(x)
a = headline_bow.transform(x)
b = headline_bow.get_feature_names()
print(a)
```

This is a sample of the output that comes out from the bag of words model:

```
  (0, 837)  1
  (0, 1496) 1
  (0, 1952) 1
  (0, 2610) 1
```

From my understanding, for "(0, 837) 1" this means that in the first list passed through the model, the 837th word in that list appears once. This makes no sense because when I print 
x[0] I get this:

```
Four ways Bob Corker skewered Donald Trump
```

There is clearly not 837 words here so im confused as to whats going on.

Here is a sample of what x is: (a bunch of headlines)

```
['Four ways Bob Corker skewered Donald Trump'
 "Linklater's war veteran comedy speaks to modern America, says star"
 'Trump’s Fight With Corker Jeopardizes His Legislative Agenda' ...
 'Ron Paul on Trump, Anarchism & the AltRight'
 'China to accept overseas trial data in bid to speed up drug approvals'
 'Vice President Mike Pence Leaves NFL Game Because of Anti-American Protests']
```

Here is the rest of my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("/Users/amanpuranik/Desktop/fake-news-detection/data.csv")
data = data[['Headline', "Label"]]

x = np.array(data['Headline'])
print(x[0])
y = np.array(data["Label"])

# tokenization of the data here'
headline_vector = []

for  headline in x:
    headline_vector.append(word_tokenize(headline))

print(headline_vector)

stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))

#removing stopwords at this part
filtered = [[word for word in sentence if word not in stopwords]
            for sentence in headline_vector]
#print(filtered)


stemmed2 = [[stem(word) for word in headline] for headline in filtered]
#print(stemmed2)

#lowercase
lower = [[word.lower() for word in headline] for headline in stemmed2] #start here

#conver lower into a list of strings
lower_sentences = [" ".join(x) for x in lower]

#organising
articles = []


for headline in lower:
    articles.append(headline)

#creating the bag of words model

    headline_bow = CountVectorizer()
headline_bow.fit(lower_sentences)
a = headline_bow.transform(lower_sentences)
print(a)
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of what x is?

Comment: I updated it display a sample of what x is

Comment: I think 837 is the word number in your feature dictionary. Which is compiled from the full vocabulary of all headlines. This is basically a sparse vector.

Comment: How would I make it so that it doesnt use the feature dictionary?

Comment: Try to think about what BOW should give you. How many *total* words do you have?

Comment: If your `x` is `x=['For ways ...', 'Linklater's war ...', 'Trump's Fight ...']` etc, I don't get your results. The result I get is that `a` is a sparse matrix with 56 stored elements. Also, getting feature names is a list `['accept', 'agenta', ...]`. In your code you are preprocessing headings into tokens. *Is* there any case that you pass your headlines tokenized?

Comment: I updated my code transformed the headlines in their tokenized form. However, i still get the same bag of words results, which is not making sense.

Comment: Please run [this code](https://repl.it/repls/MidnightblueExperiencedDeal) based on your example and compare the results.

Comment: You state: “for (0,837) 1, this means that in the first list passed through the model, the 837th word in that list appears once.” This statement is slightly wrong. It really means that the 837th word that you have ever seen (in all lists) appeared in this list once. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yea that makes sense, I understand what it is trying to tell me now.